# Android Firebase - Adding Values To Users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making an Android app with Firebase and I want to add sections to each FirebaseUser (like wins and losses) but I don't think you can add to those objects. Should I just use the Realtime Database to do this or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With Firebase, you can only use JSON. I'm not sure I entirely understand your problem. If I did, I would be able to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                 DatabaseReference ref1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                 DatabaseReference ref2,ref3;
                 ref2= ref1.child(user);//user is the name of user
                 ref2.child("Wins").setValue(""what he won);
                 ref2.child("Loose").setValue(""what he Lose);
```

Here I created a child to root node with user name, added sub children(Win & Lose) to user and then I set values to these children.

And you can retrieve that data too based on your query.

Refer following link once.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: Ya, that's what I thought I needed to do. Thanks for the help.